# ad banner size in layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

i've got simple layout xml file in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxx" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/but" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/sback"
            android:hint="Wprowadź swój adres"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but when i run my app in log cat i got this error: "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 480x75, but only has 432x730" Somebody can help my with this size troubles?

Comment: change this properties ads:adSize="BANNER" to ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly to do with the padding in your outermost LinearLayout

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Remove/reduce those.

Comment: Yeap when i removed this two lines solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Very hard one to answer without seeing a scene shot. If I was you though and was trying to solve this problem I would remove a lot from the view and keep reintroducing parts of the view till the problem returns. Then you will know what needs to be changed in the view. So maybe start here and build back up

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"


          ads:adUnitId="xxx" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Also consider defining all layout with dip units instead of "match_parent" till you find the problem. it will let you know exactly how large everything is displaying in relation to each other.

Hope this helps some what.